# How can I fingerprint Yii framework version?

Tags: web-application, fingerprinting, fingerprint

I am currently testing in a black box manner an application written in Yii framework.

How can I fingerprint Yii framework exact version? It's there a public file or function that I can use to perform such actions?

Thanks.